# Merging an iPad and iPhone codebase with different Core Data versions

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an iOS application that started life as an iPhone application. It was forked to produce an iPad version, and I'm working to integrate them back together so that I can produce both versions of the app from a single branch (using different targets in Xcode). This is mostly done, actually.

**The Problem**
As the iPad app evolved, so too did it's core data model. As a result, the app's model is currently at version 3.4 for both apps, but they are slightly different (ie. different attributes). So if I produce a merged build, one of the apps won't be able to migrate because the version of "3.4" that's out there won't match the new version.

So I ask you, oh denizens of stackoverflow ... any ideas on the best way to proceed in order to get these codebases merged?

Comment: Couldn't you just simply change the version of one and map the merge?

Comment: I don't see why the same app has two different core data models. Also, you don't really need 2 targets to have iPhone and iPad versions, because if you upload them they will be 2 different applications and you don't generally want that.

Comment: My basic advice is to shoot for a universal target instead of two targets from one code base. All the benefits you see from a single code base your users see from a single app.

Secondly you should be able to set up some custom Core Data migration using both models to create a merged model.

Comment: I should have mentioned, we are explicitly avoiding a universal target for the time being.